# Игра не запускается

Tags: javascript, html

Скрипт игры типа кто хочет стать миллионером. Ребята, прошу помочь, консоль ошибок не выдает, но игра не запускается. Заранее спасибо!

```js
var questions = [];

questions[0] = {
  q00: "Что за место, попав в которое, человек делает селфи на кухне, которую не может себе позволить? \n",
  a01: "1 - Париж \n",
  a02: "2 - Рим \n",
  a03: "3 - Венеция \n",
  a04: "4 - Икея \n",
  correctAns: 4
};
questions[1] = {
  q00: "Кто 1-м получил Нобелевскую премию по литературе? \n",
  a01: "1 - Романист",
  a02: "2 - Драматург",
  a03: "3 - Поэт",
  a04: "4 - Эссеист",
  correctAns: 3
};

questions[2] = {
  q00: "Какой химический элемент назван в честь злого подземного гнома? \n",
  a01: "1 - Гафний \n",
  a02: "2 - Кобальт \n",
  a03: "3 - Бериллий \n",
  a04: "4 - Теллур \n",
  correctAns: 2
};

  



var event;
var correctAnswer = 0;
var money = 0;
var ok = false;

function start() {
  for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    do {
      event = +prompt(questions[i].q00 + "\n" + questions[i].a01 + "\n" + questions[i].a02 + "\n" + questions[i].a03 + "\n" + questions[i].a04 + "\n" + '-1 - Exit');
      if (event == -1) {
        break;
      } else {
        ok = isAnswer(event);
      }
    } while (!ok);
    if (event == questions[i].correctAns) {
      correctAnswer++;
      if (i < 3) {
        money += 500 + "рублей";
      } else if (i >= 4 && i <= 5) {
        money += 1000 + "рублей";
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  alert("Количество верных ответов: " + correctAnswer + "Заработная сумма: " + money);
  alert("Игра закончена.Спасибо!");
}
//------------------------------------------
function isAnswer(event) {
  if (isNaN(event) || !isFinite(event)) {
    alert('Вы ввели недопустимый символ');
    return false;
  } else if (event < 1 || event > 4) {
    alert('Ваше число выходит из допустимого диапозона');
    return false;
  }
  return true;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Кто хочет стать миллионером</title>
  <script src="gameMillionareText.js"></script>
  <script src="millionare.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем коде нет вызова функций, если это не предусмотрено в других файлах, то игра и не запустится.

```
start();
```